# CSS how to change font size only on a specific table not every tables on the page?

Tags: css, background

I am trying to create a banner looking header for my page and I have trouble changing the font size within the table. When I change, all the fonts in the other tables in other webparts change also.

This is my code:

```
//style

table.mmm, th, td {
color: white;
width: 100%;
text-align: left;
font-size: 12px;
}

/style

/table class="mmm" bgcolor="#5582AB">
   /tbody> 
      /tr>
         /th> Month​
      </tr>
   /tbody> 
/table>
```

---

What should I have done correctly? Also, is there a similar thing as   in CSS?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

*table.mmm th, table.mmm td 
{ color: white; width: 100%; text-align: left; font-size: 12px; }*

Comment: Got it...! Really appreciate the help! It's always something simple that gets me!!

Comment: Always, we(developers) used to hit the head against the floor for the simple things.